# Bad filename or number : vbs error

Tags: vbscript

sry guys m new to programming. I was trying to make a vbscript to cope a vbs file from current location to system startup folder. But m getting the error bad file name or number. but when i give path manually it works like a charm. The path my code is self picking is also correct. Cant understand what is the problem. Please help me. Here is my code.

```
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
strMyPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
wscript.echo strPath
wscript.echo strMyPath
'Const strMyPath = "C:\Users\Bilal\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\"
Const SourceFile = "abc.vbs"
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
If fso.FileExists(strMyPath) Then
    'Check to see if the file is read-only
    If Not fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes And 1 Then 
        'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True
    Else 
        'The file exists and is read-only.
        'Remove the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes = fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes - 1
        'Replace the file
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True
        'Reapply the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes = fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes + 1
    End If
Else
    'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, myStrPath, True
End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: The last copy statement . The case in which file doesnt already exists.

Comment: I have commented a const variable statement. If i use that statement it works perfectly fine.

Comment: In that line, you're using `myStrPath`...which doesn't get set anywhere.

Comment: ya i saw that and corrected that.

Comment: Error is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So it should look like this:

```
   Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
   strPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Startup")
   strMyPath = strPath&"\"  
   Const SourceFile = "abc.vbs"
   strMyPath = strMyPath & SourceFile
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
    If fso.FileExists(strMyPath) Then

    'Check to see if the file is read-only
    If Not fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes And 1 Then 
        'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True
    Else 
        'The file exists and is read-only.
        'Remove the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes = fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes - 1
        'Replace the file
        fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True
        'Reapply the read-only attribute
        fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes = fso.GetFile(strMyPath).Attributes + 1
    End If
Else
    'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True
End If
Set fso = Nothing
```

Comment: i corrected that to:
    fso.CopyFile SourceFile, strMyPath, True

Answer (score 1):

To make

```
If fso.FileExists(strMyPath) Then
```

'work', strMyPath must contain a valid **file** specification. As far as I can see, in your code it contains the path to the (destination?) folder.

Use properly named variable (names)s that make clear whether they hold folder or file specs.

Comment: ya destination folder .

Comment: If it is the destination folder your trying to verify exists, why not use the ".FolderExists()" method?

Comment: As i said m new. Dont have much knowledge of fucntions.